# LWJGL window only updating the frame once per second?

Tags: java, refresh, lwjgl

From what I understand, it should be attempting to redraw the window 100 times per second. Instead, it updates a single time each second, exactly. This only started today and as far as I know I have not made any changes to the code that would affect this. Could it be that it is taking an especially long time in any of the loops, or one of them is restricting time?

```
        public class Main {

            Texture texture;
            int p1y = 3, p1x = 3;
            float VEL = 2.5f; //3.25 orig
            int[][] mapArray = new int[16][16];
            boolean[][] mapBool = new boolean[16][16];
            boolean[] contBool = new boolean[12];
            String tile = "/res/tile.jpg";
            String background = "res/background.jpg";
            boolean drewStuff = false;
            int count = 0;

            private void updateLoop() {
                if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W))
                    p1y -= 1;
                if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S))
                    p1y += 1;
                if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
                    p1x -= 1;
                if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D))
                    p1x += 1;
                specifics.start();
                }
            Timer specifics = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evx) {
                            for(int i = 1; i > 0; i--) {
                                try {
                                    setThings();
                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        });

            public void setThings() throws IOException {
                for(int i = mapArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    for(int j = mapArray[i].length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                        mapArray[i][j] = i * 40;
                    }
                }
                for(int i = contBool.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    contBool[i] = true;
                }
            }

            private void create(){
                try{
                    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
                    Display.setTitle("Electric Maze");
                    Display.create();
                    Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
                    Display.setInitialBackground(220, 220, 220);
                    initGL();
                    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
                        updateLoop();
                        render();
                        Display.update();
                        Display.sync(100);  
                    }
                    Display.destroy();
                    System.exit(0);
                }catch(LWJGLException e){

                }

            }
            private void initGL(){
                glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
                glEnable(GL_BLEND);
                glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
                glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

                glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                glLoadIdentity();
                glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, -1, 1);
                glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                glLoadIdentity();
            }

            public void drawLaser(int x, int y, int size, int dir, int loc) {
                    if(mapBool[x][y] == false) {
                            for(int i = y; count < size; i++) {
                                if(mapBool[x][i] == true)size = count;
                                size = count;
                                System.out.println(count + " - " + size);
                                count++;
                        }
                        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                            glVertex2f((mapArray[x][x + 1] + 11), mapArray[y + 1][y]);
                            glVertex2f(mapArray[x][x + 1] + 5, mapArray[y + 1][y]);
                            glVertex2f(mapArray[x][x + 1] + 5, mapArray[y + 1][y] + 40 * size);
                            glVertex2f((mapArray[x][x + 1] + 11), mapArray[y + 1][y] + 40 * size);
                        glEnd();
                    }else if(mapBool[x][y] == true)contBool[loc] = false;
            }

            public void drawTile(int x, int y, int sizeX, int sizeY, String path) {
                try {
                    texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("JPG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                    texture.bind();
                    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                    glVertex2f(mapArray[x][x + 1], mapArray[y + 1][y]);
                    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                    glVertex2f(mapArray[x][x + 1] + sizeX * 40, mapArray[y + 1][y]);
                    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                    glVertex2f(mapArray[x][x + 1] + sizeX * 40, mapArray[y + 1][y] + sizeY * 40);   //Should use accordingly sized texture when scaling
                    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                    glVertex2f(mapArray[x][x + 1], mapArray[y + 1][y] + sizeY * 40);
                    texture.release();
                glEnd();
                mapBool[x][y] = true;
            }

            public void drawPlayer() {
                int x = p1x;
                int y = p1y;
                try {
                    texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("JPG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/player.jpg"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                    texture.bind();
                    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                    glVertex2f(mapArray[x][x + 1], mapArray[y + 1][y]);
                    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                    glVertex2f(mapArray[x][x + 1] + 40, mapArray[y + 1][y]);
                    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                    glVertex2f(mapArray[x][x + 1] + 40, mapArray[y + 1][y] + 40);   //Should use accordingly sized texture when scaling
                    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                    glVertex2f(mapArray[x][x + 1], mapArray[y + 1][y] + 40);
                    texture.release();
                glEnd();
                mapBool[x][y] = true;
            }

            private void render(){
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                glColor3f(240, 240, 240);

                for(int i = contBool.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    contBool[i] = true;
                }

                /*glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                    glVertex2f(x, y);
                    glVertex2f(x+width, y);
                    glVertex2f(x+width, y+height); //How it works. Just in case. Because you're stupid, Joel.
                    glVertex2f(x, y+height);         
                glEnd();*/

                drawTile(0, 1, 15, 16, background);
                drawPlayer();

                for(int i = 14; i > 0; i--) {
                    drawTile(0, i, 1, 1, tile);
                    drawTile(14, i, 1, 1, tile);
                    drawTile(i, 13, 1, 1, tile);
                    drawTile(i, 1, 1, 1, tile);
                }

                drawTile(4, 8, 1, 1, tile);
                drawTile(7, 5, 1, 1, tile);
                drawLaser(4, 2, 5, 1, 2);
                drawLaser(7, 2, 8, 1, 3);
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                new Main().create();
            }
}
```

Comment: Anybody? I still have this issue. Tried on different PC's and IDE's same thing.

Comment: I have the same Problem, postet the same question again...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600, 32, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN)); instead of Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
```

Some unrelated stuff:
I am 14 this year and similarly I have 2 years of programming experience. Would you like to give me your email or some way of contact? I have an almost exact copy of your programming learning experience.